# How to read 0-1023 sensor value from Arduino in Swift iOS App

Tags: swift, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy, sensor-fusion

I have an Arduino BLE device sending sensor analog read int values of 0-1023.  I can read the values using the LightBlue app and reading the Characteristic using little endian.  In my iOS Swift app, I can connect to the peripheral and read my custom UUID Characteristic and report that it is in fact receiving data but I am stuck on how to print that data in the debug window.  It only says "Value received".  Ultimately I want to display that data in a UITextfield in the UI in the app.  Here's the 'didUpdateValueFor' code:

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
    

  var characteristicFUELValue = NSString()

  guard rxFuelCharacteristic == characteristic,

        let rxFuelCharacteristic = characteristic.value,
        let dataString = NSString(data: rxFuelCharacteristic, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) else { return }

    characteristicFUELValue = dataString


  print("Value Recieved: \((characteristicFUELValue as String))")

  NotificationCenter.default.post(name:NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "Notify"), object: "\((characteristicFUELValue as String))")
}
```

And here is the debug window readout:

Is Powered On.
Function: centralManager(*:didDiscover:advertisementData:rssi:),Line: 160
Peripheral Discovered: <CBPeripheral: 0x283331b80, identifier = B9EC3226-BC71-A657-B78A-A62B63FBB01B, name = Arduino, mtu = 0, state = disconnected>
Function: centralManager(*:didDiscover:advertisementData:rssi:),Line: 160
Duplicate Found.
Peripheral Discovered: <CBPeripheral: 0x283331b80, identifier = B9EC3226-BC71-A657-B78A-A62B63FBB01B, name = Arduino, mtu = 0, state = disconnected>
Found 1 characteristics.
My Characteristic: D1DF5080-8938-11EC-A8A3-0242AC120002

---

Function: peripheral(_:didUpdateNotificationStateFor:error:),Line: 297
Characteristic's value subscribed
Subscribed. Notification has begun for: D1DF5080-8938-11EC-A8A3-0242AC120002
Value Recieved: Value Recieved: Value Recieved: Value Recieved: Value Recieved: Value Recieved: Value Recieved: Value Recieved: Value Recieved: Value Recieved: Value Recieved: Value Recieved: Value Recieved:

Any help would be so appreciated.  Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned that you want to read the value **as Int**, but in code you are trying to read the value **as String**.

If your are sure your data has at least 2 bytes, read it as UInt16:

`let fuelValue: UInt16 = rxFuelCharacteristic.withUnsafeBytes { $0.load(as: UInt16.self) }`

It you're not sure about the data size, I suggest to implement Data extension with `readFuelValue()` function, here is the playground:

```
import Foundation

extension Data {
    func readFuelValue() -> UInt? {
        if count >= 2 {
            return UInt(withUnsafeBytes { $0.load(as: UInt16.self) })
        } else if count == 1 {
            return UInt(withUnsafeBytes { $0.load(as: UInt8.self) })
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}

func demo(_ bytes: [UInt8]) {
    let data = Data(bytes)
    let fuelValue = data.readFuelValue()
    print("\(bytes) => \(fuelValue)")
}

demo([])
demo([0])
demo([5])
demo([0x00, 0x00])
demo([0x09, 0x00])
demo([0xFF, 0x00])
demo([0x00, 0x01])
demo([0x00, 0x02])
demo([0x01, 0x02])
demo([0x01, 0x02, 150])
```

The output is:

```
[] => nil
[0] => Optional(0)
[5] => Optional(5)
[0, 0] => Optional(0)
[9, 0] => Optional(9)
[255, 0] => Optional(255)
[0, 1] => Optional(256)
[0, 2] => Optional(512)
[1, 2] => Optional(513)
[1, 2, 150] => Optional(513)
```

Comment: Thanks @alexander! I can tell you that i am receiving 4 bytes so would I still be okay with the UInt16?

Comment: If the value is 0-1023 then UInt16 is enough (UInt16 can hold 0-65535). The final solution will depend on the device which sends the data, because 4 bytes could mean "1 value of 4 bytes", or "2 separate values, 2 bytes per each", or something else. If you are sure it's only one integer value, you can use UInt32. Also be sure to check if data is 4 bytes, because `load(as: UInt32.self)` will crash if the size is not enough to read the wanted value type.